# Can't Krishna(God) be considered a friend?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, bhakti, friendship

In Bhagwat geeta verse 41-42 of chapter 11 has mentioned that "arjun is asking for pardon to call krishna as friend, making joke with him"

Does that mean we can't consider krishna as a friend?

Is there any Documentary (Scriptural) proof of it that God can pe prayed in any desired form, even as friend?

Specially is there any verse in Srimad Bhagwat Geeta describing God as friend?

(Of course then why Krishna consider sudama, and all Gwala as friend and even eat their Food, I know it need highly devoted but still can't we perform devotion in a form of friend and God just like meera bai, surdas ji and all did?)

Comment: Well what really matters is the 'bhaav', the feelings, everything else is not a matter of concern. You can refer to Krishna as a friend, teacher, father, brother, son, as your master etc etc

Comment: That i Know, but i was just looking for any written statement, specially in bhagwat geeta.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, I don't think Bhagavad Gita 5.29 is saying anything about Arjuna asking Krishna to pardon him for regarding him as a friend. If anything Krishna proclaims himself to be the friend of all creatures. Here's the verse translated by Swami Gambhirananda from the Ramakrishna Mission.

> One attains Peace by knowing Me who, as the great Lord of all the worlds, am the enjoyer of sacrifices and austerities, (and) who am the friend of all creatures

Comment: Am sorry sir, now I have correct ed actually somehow this verse was roaming in my mind. And yeah About that verse  It's actually sanskrit translation of last line is not "my friend" It's " Reside in me and I reside in him" That's why I was kind of upset